# Unity move object in orbit of another object based on mouse(drag) position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a simulation that takes place in the universe.

What I want to achieve is to move (by mouse or touch) an object around the planet at a fixed distance.

I've tried to use the `RotateAround` function that Unity provides, however I don't know how to take the mouse position into consideration when using that function.

Comment: So...? What have you tried? What is your question? StackOverflow is not for asking "Please someone (tell me how to) implement XY for me" but rather about "Please someone help me with this specific issue I encountered while implementing this specific code I added to my question where I try to achieve XY but instead ZZ happens". Please make sure to take the  [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also refer to [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @derHugo As you know if asker already has a working solution [it's best to put it in an answer and omit it from the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/405359) which they have indeed done. Is it quite right to ask such a person to modify their working solution so that it breaks and then include that intentionally broken code in the question? This particular question would be more improved if it contained more details about the use case however...

Comment: @Ruzihm answering the own question is fully ok and acceptable. However, this still doesn't make this a valid question for StackOverflow as it is completely and way to broad and as you say not clear what the desired outcome is without looking at the answer ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I did is the following.
First I check if the mouse is pressed. If so I will get the mouse position and convert it to a position in the world space. I want to ignore the z because I don't want to move it in the z axis. But you could leave the z there if you want to move it in the z axis also.

Afterwards I check the direction from the planet to the mouse position. To keep it in orbit I will use the the fixed distance that is stored in maxDistance.

And finally if I want the object to look at the planet I will use LookAt.

```
public void Start()
{
    maxDistance = Vector3.Distance(planet.position, transform.position);
}

public void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        var planetPos = planet.position;
        var t = transform;
        var mousePos = mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        mousePos = new Vector3(mousePos.x, mousePos.y, planetPos.z);
        var dir = (mousePos - planetPos).normalized;
        t.position = planetPos + dir * maxDistance;
        t.LookAt(planetPos, Vector3.right);
    }
}
```